# Integrating Tumblr API within my IOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, social-networking, tumblr

I am trying to integrate Tumblr API with IOS app using TMTumblrSDK , I am still finding it difficult,It is giving me some unknown behaviour. It Means getting reponse like not authorized 401. I have tried Oauth also but still not getting perfect solution. help me if u have any solution.

I am requesting for some concrete solution for Integrating Tumblr.

Thank you in advance.

[link](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the Below link with Example also .

[Tumble integration](https://github.com/manileo86/iOSTumblrConnect)

Hope it work for you

Comment: thank you for your help. its working now

Comment: @dipenmajithiya please accept the answer its usefull for someone  else

Comment: I tried this example, but encountered error: ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice for libOAuth.a. Did you encounter this error?

Comment: What do you have to insert for kTumblrAppCallbackURL ?